# Deleting old branches in console

Tags: git, console

What is the command for destroying all the old branches in the console memory? Is their a way to get rid of all of them at once?

Here is what I see

[image]

I want to delete all branches.

Comment: _When you are in master branch_, `git branch | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D `. This keeps `master` branch. I could be mistaken, but you cannot delete the current branch you are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be mistaken, but you cannot delete the current branch you are in, however, you can delete the rest of the branches at once (locally).

When you are in master branch:

```
git branch | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D
```

You can replace "master" with the branch you are in, to delete the others.

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/x3jmig/remove-all-your-local-git-branches-but-keep-master